# Python - how to compare all items within list

Tags: python, list, loops, pyqt, pyside

As python starter, trying to get help from smart people when encountered the problem. And that is now:

I got to compare items (Qt scene items) from one list among each other, and make separate groups of items which collides mutually.

Please help me with code :

```
class MainWin(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWin, self).__init__()
        self.Win()
        self.L = self.buildAllWalls()
        items = self.scene.items()
        allGroups = groupItemsFromList(None, items)
        self.paintGroups(allGroups)
        print len(allGroups)

    def paintGroups(self, groups):
        for g in groups :
            color = QColor(0, 0, 0)
            # RANDOM COLOR
            namcol = "#%s" % "".join([hex(randrange(0, 255))[2:] for i in range(3)])
            color.setNamedColor(namcol)
            while color.isValid() == False :   #   ERROR CHECK
                namcol = "#%s" % "".join([hex(randrange(0, 255))[2:] for i in range(3)])
                color.setNamedColor(namcol)
            pen = QPen(color, 14, Qt.SolidLine)
            for w in g :
                w.setPen(pen)

    def Win(self):
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.sView = QGraphicsView(self.scene)
        self.sView.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.sView.setAlignment( Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop )

        self.setCentralWidget(self.sView)
        self.setGeometry(20, 380, 400, 300)
        self.show()

    def buildAllWalls(self):
        data = self.wallCoordinates()
        for p in range(len(data)) :
            ptA = QPointF(data[p][0], data[p][1])
            ptB = QPointF(data[p][2], data[p][3])
            self.wall(ptA, ptB)

    def wall(self, ptA, ptB):
        pen = QPen(QColor(100, 100, 100), 14, Qt.SolidLine)
        currL = self.scene.addLine(QLineF(ptA.x(), ptA.y(), ptB.x(), ptB.y()))
        currL.setPen(pen)
        return currL

    #[50,75,325,75],
    def wallCoordinates(self):
        data = [[50,100,150,100],[175,200,125,200],[175,275,125,275],[175,275,175,200],
            [150,150,150,100],[175,100,225,100],[250,100,325,100],[350,125,175,125],
            [50,125,125,125],[125,175,125,125],[150,150,175,150],[175,150,175,200],
            [50,150,100,150],[100,150,100,200],[100,200,125,200],[50,175,75,175],
            [75,225,75,175],[75,225,125,225],[125,275,125,225]]
        return data

def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWin()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: what is your problem and what is the output needed?

Comment: As just explained, I need to compare item list members among each other to make lists of groups which collides.

Comment: Note that for boolean and, use the `and` operator, not `&`.

Comment: what does the `collidesWithItem()` function do

Comment: if you just want to see what elements are in both, cast the lists to a python set, and do s.intersection(t)

Comment: collidesWithItem() is method fro Qt library for collision detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would write this:

```
def groupItemsFromList(self, itemList):
    tmp = itemList[:]
    allGroups = []
    while tmp:
        it = tmp.pop(0)  
        currentGroup = [it]
        # loop from back to front so we can remove items safely
        for i in range(len(tmp)-1, -1, -1):
            if it.collidesWithItem(tmp[i]):
                currentGroup.append(tmp.pop(i))
        allGroups.append(currentGroup)
    return allGroups
```

For example:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
    def collidesWithItem(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, self.__class__) and self.key == other.key
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{0}({1})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.key)

example = [Test(1), Test(2), Test(1), Test(1), Test(3), Test(2), Test(3), Test(4)]
print groupItemsFromList(None, example)
```

Output:

```
[[Test(1), Test(1), Test(1)], [Test(2), Test(2)], [Test(3), Test(3)], [Test(4)]]
```

This makes the assumption that all items that collide with an item will also collide with each other.

**edit: Sounds like the assumption was not valid, try the following (untested):**

```
def groupItemsFromList(self, itemList):
    tmp = itemList[:]
    allGroups = []
    while tmp:
        it = tmp.pop(0)  
        currentGroup = [it]
        i = len(tmp) - 1
        while i >= 0:
            if any(x.collidesWithItem(tmp[i]) for x in currentGroup):
                currentGroup.append(tmp.pop(i))
                i = len(tmp) - 1
            else:
                i -= 1
        allGroups.append(currentGroup)
    return allGroups
```

Comment: +1, and have to test it. I wish to check True to all of you guys here for taking your time for explaining me. Much obliged.

Comment: Today I tested your code. While your test passing, try to implement it and noticed that subgroups have only 2 items, ignoring others. Please, can you check it again. I could post the code.

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure I understand the issue.  If possible please try to provide a minimal example that shows the problem.  For example, if you could come up with an example like "For the list `[A, B, C, D, E]`, where `A` collides with `B` and `C` collides with ..., the result is `[[A, B], [C, ...]]` when it should be `[[A, B], ...]`".

Comment: Your code works with integers like charm. But I don't know what's going on, trying whole day to detect. Therefore I edited executable code here WITH YOURS CODE in it which you can copy and run. It is the best way to look what is achieved, of course, if Qt is installed. There's no point otherwise, example picture is at http://top.com.hr/result/2ndAttempt.png . If not, don't bother, and very thanks for your time.

Comment: Not completely sure I understand, in that image should the connected green, purple, and dark blue segments all be the same color?

Comment: That's it. You understood the problem, and you solve it. Works beautiful. In mean time, I figure while it's not working, but couldn't fix it. You did it all, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>It looks like you could do this:</strike>

```
def groupItemsFromList(self, itemList):
    """
    Make a list of lists, where each list is composed of the
    items (excepting itself, of course) that an item collides with.
    """
    return [
        [item for item in itemList[:i] + itemList[i:] if item.collidesWithItem(x)]
        for i, x in enumerate(itemList)
    ]
```

`itemList[:i] + itemList[i:]` is python idiom for "I want all elements of the original list except the i'th item."

---

Later: I see. You want something more like this:

```
def groupItemsFromList(self, itemList):
    def collision_indexes(i, target):
        return [i] + [j for j, item in enumerate(itemList[i + 1:], start=i + 1) if item.collidesWithItem(target)]

    processed = set()
    results = []
    for i, target in enumerate(itemList):
        if i not in processed:
            indexes = collision_indexes(i, target)
            processed.update(indexes)
            results.append([itemList[j] for j in indexes])
    return results
```

The only advantage here is that this is side-effect-free code. There is no mutation to the original data but only functions applied to the data and changes made to new, temporary data structures.

Comment: +1...I'm going to put it on test. I have to admit, your comprehensive code shocked me! Wow!

Comment: It almost do the job, in fact, it overdo it. Copies some items few times more. Can you improve it, please? Anyway thanks a huge.

Comment: `Copies some items few times more.` Please give an example with data and desired output.

Comment: However, I checked F.J's answer for its accuracy, but you are my hero and I will take look at your other answers here at SO...check your score :).

Comment: Well,sure you can do that, but StackOverflow monitoring commonly concludes that there is collusion when one person's score shoots up because some other person upvotes another in such a concentration.

Comment: I was moderate. And your other answers are worth to look at.

Comment: On my test, upper, checked answer not passing my test since it puts in subgroup max 2 collided items. Updated problem fully executable. Any help?

Comment: That's better, your code achieves max.3 items in group, while in largest group should be 12 items. Interesting, yours solution achieves total 10 subgroups same as upper written code. The total subgroups should be 5. Thanks.